# Change the start of the year in moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, prototypejs, momentjs

I am using momentJS for date calculations.

Here I want to change start of year for weeks calculation.

For me start of year will be 1-nov and end will be 31-oct.

or any other JS date lib that allows me to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/EvLmF/

```
var EndDate = moment([2008, 0, 29]);//End Date
var StartDate = moment([2007, 0, 28]);//Start Date

alert("Weeks : " + EndDate.diff(StartDate, 'weeks'));
alert("Days : " + EndDate.diff(StartDate, 'days'));
alert("Years : " + EndDate.diff(StartDate, 'years'));
```

So create new moment objects with your start date and end date and perform operations as required.